# Same CSS showing different fonts in two pages

Tags: php, html, css, fonts

In my webiste, I used  `font-family: 'Caesar Dressing',cursive,"brushsci";`

But it shows two differnt fonts in two pages.

See the `header menu` fonts in following links :

http://www.berzerkart.com/

http://www.berzerkart.com/store/Charlo

I checked it in firebug, in the first link `Caesar Dressing` is active
and in the second link `cursive` is active,

I want same style for both, what could be the issue.

Comment: Keywords like _cursive_ should always be the last font in the list. They are fallback fonts and the browsers won't look further than those. In your example, "brushsci" will never be used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include the Google Font in your head tags on all pages it is being used.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caesar+Dressing' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: Right, because it is included in the head tag on the first link.  On the second link, I do not see it.